# Custom log processing/parsing

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep, go

I have such log format:

```
[26830431.7966868][4][0.013590574264526367][30398][api][1374829886.320353][init] 
  GET /foo
  {"controller"=>"foo", "action"=>"index"}

[26830431.7966868][666][2.1876697540283203][30398][api][1374829888.4944339][request_end] 
  200 OK
```

The entry is constracted using such pattern:

```
[request_id][user_id][time_from_request_started][process_id][app][timestamp][tagline]
  payload
```

Durring request I have many point where I log something - app basically has complex behaviour. This helps me debug a lot the user behaviour.

The way I would like to parse it is that I would like to make have directory structure like this:

```
req_id
  |
  |----[time_from_request_started][process_id][timestamp][tagline]
  |
  etc
```

Basically each directory will have name based on req_id, with files wchich names are rest of  tagline. These files will include payload.

And also I will have other directory, with users ids, which will contain symlinks to request done by this user.

**First question: Is this structure correct?** In my opinion it will make easy fast log access. The reason I want to use directories and files is that I like unix approach, and try it (feel by myself its drawbacks and advantages)

**Second question:** I will have no problem to use ruby for creating this. But I would like to learn some new tool, which is better suited for this. I am thinking about using just unix tools (pipe, awk etc) to achieve this, or write parser in golang which I am learning right now (even have time to implement simple map reduce). **What tool is best suited for this?**

Answer (score 1):

I would not store logs in a directory to see how the users behave.

Depending on what behaviour you want to keep track of you could use different tools. One of these could be [mixpanel](https://mixpanel.com/) or [keen.io](https://keen.io/).

Instead of logging what the user did in a log file you would sent an event to either of those (they are pretty similar, pick the one you think has better docs / lib), then you would graph those events to better understand the behaviour of your users. I've done this a lot recently, to display data in a nice way I've used [rickshaw](http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/).

The key point why I'm suggesting this is that if you go the file route you will still have to find a way to understand your data, something that graphs will help you a lot at. Also, visualization is something keen.io does by default, you may still want to do your graphs but it's a good start.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Interesting poing, I will try to implement this and check how it fullfil my needs. Good point is that I can reply current log there!

Answer (score 0):

> Is this structure correct?

Only you can know that, it depends directly on how the data needs be accessed and used.

> What tool is best suited for this?

You could probably use UNIX tools to achieve this but it may as well be a good exercise to practice your Go skills by writing this. It would also be more extensible.